# Java package names when contributing to some other open-source project on github

Tags: java, github, open-source

Just a noob question I guess, but what package names should I use if I am adding a new feature/java project to an existing github project by a big multi-national?

Should I use my own or is it OK if I use that company's reverse domain, even though I am not an employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When contributing to an existing project you should follow the package names that already exist in the project. For example, if you're contributing to the FooBar project that has all its classes under a structure of `com.somecompany.foo.bar`, so should your contributions, even if you're not an employee of Somecompany.

At most, if you're contributing a new concept to the project that deserves its own sub-package, you can create it **within** the given package structure. In the previous example, you could create a new `com.somecompany.foo.bar.newidea`.

Note, BTW, most open source projects would have `org.projectname` packages, not `com.companyname`.

Comment: Thanks for the info... btw, my current as well as previous employers both use com.employer for their github projects, and one of them is a JSR Standard RI (we are the maintainers of the standard)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should conform to their existing package naming. If they have open-sourced it, they are indicating that they welcome contributions from the wider community, but it is still one coherent project which should conform to a consistent set of rules and naming conventions.

On the other hand, if it's something like a plugin system, where other authors would contribute to an eco-system surrounding the project, you might consider making you're own repository with your own convention for a specific plugin.